# Blank result for criteria not matching IN() statement

Tags: sql, intersystems-cache

I have a large list of IDs and I need to populate some information from a database.  I would like my query results to show gaps in the data.  This is hard to describe, but given this data:

[image: Sample data]

And this query:

```
SELECT ID, Name, Color FROM myTable
WHERE ID IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7')
```

I would like these results:

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: yes.  you'll need a table that lists all the id's possible, and then left join your color table on id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a table of values using a recursive CTE and then join to that table to find your missing values.

```
;with CTE AS (
SELECT 1 AS col_

UNION ALL 

SELECT 1 + col_
FROM cte

WHERE col_ <100
)

SELECT col_, mt.*
FROM cte

LEFT JOIN myTable mt
ON mt.id = col_
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a function....

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.BreakStringIntoRows (@CommadelimitedString   varchar(1000))
RETURNS   @Result TABLE (Ret VARCHAR(100))
AS
BEGIN
        DECLARE @IntLocation INT
        WHILE (CHARINDEX(',',    @CommadelimitedString, 0) > 0)
        BEGIN
              SET @IntLocation =   CHARINDEX(',',    @CommadelimitedString, 0)      
              INSERT INTO   @Result (Ret)
              --LTRIM and RTRIM to ensure blank spaces are   removed
              SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@CommadelimitedString,   0, @IntLocation)))   
              SET @CommadelimitedString = STUFF(@CommadelimitedString,   1, @IntLocation,   '') 
        END
        INSERT INTO   @Result (Ret)
        SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(@CommadelimitedString))--LTRIM and RTRIM to ensure blank spaces are removed
        RETURN 
END
```

### Select statement

```
SELECT 
    Id = B.Ret, 
    Name = ISNULL(T.Name, ''), 
    Color = ISNULL(T.Color, '') 
FROM dbo.BreakStringIntoRows('1,2,3,4,5,6,7') AS B
LEFT JOIN myTable T ON B.Ret = T.Id
```

### Result

[image: Result]

Hope it helps.